# Dawanda oAuth Login and Example

Tags: api, authentication, oauth

i have a question.
I didnt found eny examples of the dawanda.com online-shop API.
I try to login as a dawanda user an see my orders. But all i found was this GitHub Repo:
https://github.com/dawanda/dawanda-api-client-js

And this "small" Documentation:
http://de.dawanda.com/oauth_clients/info

[NEW]
DaWanda has a new REST API
https://de.dawanda.com/apps/seller_api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems only the PHP "Framework" / SDK has the oAuth-Function:
https://github.com/dawanda/dawanda-api-client-php

:/

[NEW]

DaWanda has a new REST API
https://de.dawanda.com/apps/seller_api

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is an open standard for authorization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth.

Its not specific to the dawanda platform. There are libraries for nearly every programming language / framework available.